# Is there any open source tool to verify segwit transaction without publishing it?

Tags: transactions, transaction-verification

I have created below transaction:

```
020000000001016c6bb8dbaa1e6b25d1267487b22206275c90a5aa8c28eb3c3aa87c97d717cf460000000017160014b6f9a9a9f51190e22798f85983c4f53fab1385a4ffffffff01faba00000000000017a914d6894287b4a028cd75ee8649ea3d59dba76ee55487024730440220373a133c6cbb6086d3e6c7152b3dda362c54dd7b2cdee60f40b862bd4cc4e012022008f034ac4c955e78a33833e485590e7598a9a19cd2196901e2e6f4d147dac4030121029d7cf71205e62ff34ff56ccd695e073397bf3330879dad2d2ffeff703748feb800000000
```

This is P2SH-P2WPKH signed transaction created by my python program. My intention is to validate my code without loosing bitcoins in the process. I did not find an option in bitcoin-cli to validate it. If there is any open source bitcoin client or online tool i can use to validate it, it will help in my testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `testmempoolaccept` RPC command if you're spending an existing output.

But setting up a regtest to make fake transaction is preferable.